# Change YouTube Thumb Up Color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, youtube

How can I change the color of the thumbs up SVG on YouTube in Devtools [For Chrome Ext]?

For some reason, it doesn't go with this variable:
sass

```
:root
    *
        --yt-spec-text-primary: #1cae23
```

[image: YT Thumbs Up Icon White, instead of Green]

Here a picture of the HTML of the YouTube Thumbs Up Button

[image: HTML]

I want it to be outlined in Green like the dislike button, and also to be filled in with green after the animation.

Like this:
[image: Green Filled In]

EDIT:

Now it goes from Green for 1 second then back to white?

[image: Green for 1 second]

[image: White for the rest]

EDIT (2):

Also tried turning off Ambient mode, doesn't affect Like Button.

Comment: 1) How do you change it? In Devtools? and 2) why did you tag the question as `google-chrome-extension`?

Comment: @wOxxOm, Sorry for not clarifying, yes I'm trying to make a chrome extension. However, I still can't even change it in Devtools either. Nothing I've tried so far as worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can now live in peace.

I've found the answer to my problem.

SASS:

```scss
.yt-spec-button-shape-next__icon
    & > yt-icon
        & > yt-animated-icon
            filter: invert(43%) sepia(95%) saturate(702%) hue-rotate(81deg) brightness(97%) contrast(89%)
```

[image: The final product of the filter]